# dynamic UIStackView inside of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uistackview

Due to the extensive updates since iOS7, I wanted to ask this question because of my limited experience with autolayout and the new stackview, and I am wondering what is the best design practice to implement the following in Objective-C (not swift yet):

[image]

In my view, there is a container scroll view, with a child container UIView. Within this UIView, there are a number of elements. One of the elements is a stack of UIViews which differ in number once in a while.

This element is followed by a map and other views.

This is how I plan on organizing it: 
[image]

**Questions**

1. Is this the correct thing to do? How would I modify the height constraint for the stackview when I remove and add elements programmatically?
2. How do you add a subview to the UIStackView through interface builder? When I do, the subview takes the size of the containing stackview.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4.2**

If you want use code instead of story board, i create an example using auto layout that don't need to estimate size of content.

you just need to add to stack view or remove from it and scroll height modify automatically.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(scrollViewContainer)
        scrollViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(redView)
        scrollViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(blueView)
        scrollViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(greenView)

        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        scrollViewContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollViewContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollViewContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollViewContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        // this is important for scrolling
        scrollViewContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()

        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return scrollView
    }()

    let scrollViewContainer: UIStackView = {
        let view = UIStackView()

        view.axis = .vertical
        view.spacing = 10

        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    let redView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500).isActive = true
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()

    let blueView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        return view
    }()

    let greenView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1200).isActive = true
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        return view
    }()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So you might want to make the whole layout contained within the stackview.  Just something to consider.

1. There isn't really any right way to do things.  I would not set a height constraint on your UIStackView (do add a width constraint that's equal to the view's width).  Only set it on the elements you add to the stack view.  You will get an error, but it's just IB complaining until you add an element to your UIStackView.

To size the elements in your stackview, you have to set a horizontal constraint on them.  You can then modify that single horizontal constraint in code to change the height of the object.

2. To add a subview you simply do:

   stackView.addArrangedSubview(childVC.view)

Or in interface builder, you just drag the element into the stack view.  Make sure it has that horizontal constraint or it will resize on you.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. I followed your direction and set the height constraint of the stackview to intrinsic and checked it off. I am now able to add views instantiated from xibs to the stackview, but I get the error  ***The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint:** when I try and constrain the width of the view to the width of the stackview. (After adding the view as an arranged subview)